# Installation of Ubuntu 13.10 desktop from ISO file

Tags: 13.10, system-installation

I downloaded `ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso` from my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. How to install `ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso` from my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Comment: I think we assume you really do mean **13.10**, and not 13.04 ..

Answer (score 0):

You must write the ISO to USB or CD/DVD as an ISO image using special tools like UNetBootIn or Brasero respectively (not just like your are saving a file); ISO image must have boot record

- then insert your usb or cd into the machine
- reboot the machine
- quickly access your BIOS with hotkey on your keyboard (mine is <kbd>Delete</kbd>) some machines is different (you must first know what that is)

  you can always restart your machine and hit hotkey to access bios before boot
- you must find the boot selection in your BIOS

  - (select cdrom if you have CD)
  - (select USB to boot is USB iso)
- with your cd or usb in your machine at restart the installation should begin by itself, be patient for this, the screen might go blank or black for a minute
- when install is complete, the program will say to restart machine

  do not take out your disk or usb
- upon restart - access again your BIOS
- change boot to HDD (hard drive you have installed OS on)
- let machine boot up from HD with new installation

you can repeat these tasks if you need to

Practice makes perfect!!! Good Luck.

Comment: Going from **10.04 LTS** to 13.10 is a fresh install. So you need external media (USB preferred method) to do this.